# Create multiple subnets across a number of VPCs on AWS using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, vpc

I want to create a terraform script that creates a number of VPCs. Then, I want my script to create 'n' subnets in all the VPCs. I want to do that in one subnet resource block. I'm able to create VPCs using count inside the resource block, but unable to use it with subnet. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your Terraform code and explain why what you're doing doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such provision for your requirement directly in Terraform, but we can tweak the count to fulfill your requirement.
First, create a resource block that creates some number of VPCs.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  count = "${var.vpc_count}"
  cidr_block           = "${element(var.cidr_prefix, count.index)}.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_support   = "true"
  enable_dns_hostnames = "true"

  tags {
    Name = "${var.vpc_name}${count.index}"
  }
}
```

You can use interpolation for count as well by passing the value through your variables.tf file or .tfvars file.

Now use this script to create "count" number of subnets in all the VPCs and distributed evenly across all the availability zones.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet" {
  count = "${var.subnet_count * var.vpc_count}"
  vpc_id            = "${element(aws_vpc.main.*.id, count.index % var.vpc_count)}"
  cidr_block        = "${element(var.cidr_prefix, count.index)}.${count.index}.0/24"
  availability_zone = "${element(data.aws_availability_zones.all.names, count.index)}"

  tags {
    Name = "${var.vpc_name}-${element(var.availability_zone, count.index)}-${count.index}"
  }
}
```

You can seperately define VPC Cidr blocks as a list and subnets CIDR blocks as a list. Although I have used a CIDR prefix and used count to configure the value of CIDR blocks for subnets.

Have a look at the variable cidr_prefix.

```
variable "cidr_prefix"{
  type = "list"
  description = "The first 16 bits of the desired cidr block/s. Note: The number of elements in the list should not be less than the specified count of VPCs."
  default = ["172.16", "10.0", "143.14", "100.10"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Shiv - This is a good solution, which I was also able to achieve using variable lists.

The challenge comes if you want to take this further to create route table associations to only specific subnets created.

imagine a Design:

- 3 vpc's created (mgmt-vpc, shared-vpc & dedicated-vpc)
- 2 AZs in each vpc (az-1a & az-1b)
- 2 subnets in each AZ ( pub-sub-az-1a & pvt-sub-az-1a) [in total 12 subnets -- 6 pub & 6 pvt]
- 2 route tables (mgmt-vpc-pub-rt & mgmt-vpc-pvt-rt)

Not so 'NEAT & SMART' Solution: Noted out subnets element IDs from the plan to modify my out variables, so that correct subnets are tagged. But this is a work-around, as involves manual steps which might bring in errors.

- create output variable for each subnet by

  output "mgmt_pvt_subnet-1" {
  value = aws_subnet.fg-pvt-sub[0].id
  }
- create multiple route table association by referring the output variable

  resource "aws_route_table_association" "mgmt-pvt-subnet-rt-assn" {
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.fg-pvt-rt.id
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.fg-pvt-sub[0].id
  }

Challenge:
issues comes when you have to 'cherry pick' the private subnets belonging to mgmt-vpc to be associated to the mgmt-vpc-pvt-rt.

I'v tried using count, for, for_each, conditions but i'm not able to achieve my goal...

Any pointers would be really appreciated